# Testing for nil to determine if counted on grid

Tags: ruby, null

I am going through the Learn to Program book by Chris Pine and in one of the chapters, there is an recursive exercise that counts 'land' if it connects to your starting point.  It is supposed to fail when the 'land' extends to the borders.  I have searched and read the other solutions and understand how to fix and handle this.

My question is:  Why does the below code work?

The code fails when I change the 'M' in the first row to an 'o'.  Shouldn't the below still generate the # NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass?

```
M = 'land'
o = 'water'

world = [[o,o,o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o],
     [o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o,o],
     [o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,M,M,o],
     [o,M,M,M,o,o,o,o,o,M,o],
     [o,o,o,M,o,M,M,o,o,o,o],
     [o,o,o,o,M,M,M,M,o,o,o],
     [o,o,o,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,o],
     [o,o,o,M,M,o,M,M,M,o,o],
     [o,o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o],
     [o,M,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o],
     [o,o,o,o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o]]

def continent_size world, x, y
    if world [y] [x] == nil
        return 0
    elsif world [y] [x] != 'land'   
        return 0
    end

size = 1
world [y] [x] = 'counted land'

size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y-1)
size = size + continent_size(world, x  , y-1)
size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y-1)
size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y  )
size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y  )
size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y+1)
size = size + continent_size(world, x  , y+1)
size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y+1)

size
end

puts continent_size(world, 5, 5)
```

Comment: Where is the starting point? What does it mean to fail? You understood how to fix what? Which part of the code that you do not understand why it works?

Comment: The page cuts off but I am starting at x, y values of 5, 5.  When the code fails, it generates a # NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass?    Another post tells me:  "This will fail when y is outside the grid. This is because world[y] will be nil, which then raises an exception trying to reference [x]; i.e. world[y][x] would read nil[x]."  I do not understand why the above returns 31 instead of an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that having that `M` on the first row avoids the error is because it is acting like a land bridge to the bottom `M`.

[image]

That `M` on the first row has coordinates `x=5` and `y=0`. Since this is `land`, one of its "adjacent" moves is to `x=6` and `y=-1`. This is the element

```
world[-1][6]
```

Since `world` has 11 rows, this is the same as

```
world[10][6]
```

given that ruby interprets negative indices to count from the end of the array. Lo and behold, there is an `M` at this position, so in a sense it has gone around the world to the other side, like settlers crossing the Bering Strait. It does this and subsequently marks it as `counted land` before the normal progression down to the bottom. So this is how that element gets counted in this case.

*Without* the `M` in the first row, it will eventually get down to the bottom `M` at `world[10][6]` and then attempt to go beyond it to `world[11][5]` at which point the error is thrown since `world[11]` is `nil`.

So it's the early settlers who get there first by going around the world, like the Native American Indians, who save this program from crashing.

(Hey it's Friday afternoon here :)